# How to know which camera a photo was taken by on android?

Tags: android, camera, exif, photos

I got a requirement to know which images were taken by the front camera and which were taken by the back camera on android device, i tried with SQLiteEditor to read system images database, but there is no useful information about which camera the images were taken by, also i tried with Exif Viewer, and the only thing may help are the FNumber and ApertureValue, here is the data copy from my Nexus5, running the newest lollipop system.

1. all the photos taken by front camera

FNumber f/2.4 ApertureValue 2.52

1. all the photos taken by back camera

FNumber f/2.9 ApertureValue 3.07

This is a part of exif data of the photos on my phone, i don't have other device, i want to know what's the relationship between those two values with two cameras on android device ? Is that information is enough to know which camera a photo was taken by ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is undoable. You can make guesses at most from the exif data it seems and your recognition will quite likely fail on other devices.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already tried on another android device and the values are different, maybe i should try some other ways.Thanks!